# I am using the fine uploader plugin and having trouble using the delete file feature after upload

Tags: file-upload, fine-uploader

Base on their document http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/25/delete-an-uploaded-file-in-3-3/, there is the UUID of the file to be deleted sent server with teh delte request.
But I have been trying the whole day and i cant get it to work.

For example here is a UUID of a file "1a2c636f-04f0-48c3-956f-22274a93b82f", i don't know how to use this to delete a the file. Should it be decrypted with some form of function first.

This might be a simply thing, but i don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UUID for a file is passed along with each request.  You must associate this UUID with the actual file server-side.  When the DELETE request comes in, find the file associated with the passed UUID, delete it, and return a 200 response.

Looking at the [server-side readme](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/server/) again, I realize that the presence of this parameter in each request is probably not documented very well.  I just updated the documentation to add another reference to this parameter.